# High quality USB microphone that works on the iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, usb, microphone

Can you recommend a high quality USB microphone that works on the iPhone 4? (Apparently there are issues with the iPhone 4 and USB microphones)

Comment: Do USB devices even work at all with the iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

By "there are issues with the iPhone 4 and USB microphones," are you referring to the fact that no one has ever gotten them to work together?

The iPad, yes—but not the iPhone 4.

(Which, I think, answers the question about which mic I recommend…)

Comment: Is it that bad? Well, I'll keep the question open, this may be resolved when iOS 4.2 is released.

Comment: 4.2 is released

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Tascam IM2 is the only game in town (and just released). Its features are 125dB SPL, 95dB S/N, 20Hz-20kHz, if eBay listings are believable.